# NOT Remember selected rows in a kendo grid if I scroll past the first 20 records, because it then gets the data from the 21st row onwards

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

This is how the grid looks like.

```
@{
                
                                    Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
                                        .Name("Processes")
                                        .AutoBind(false)
                                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                            .Ajax()
                                            .PageSize(20)
                                            .Read(read => read.Action("GetTasksKendo", "TaskManager", new { getBy = ViewBag.Filter, workType = ViewBag.WorkType }).Data("additionalInfo")).ServerOperation(false)
                                         )
                                         .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid-header" })
                                        .Columns(columns =>
                                        {
                                            columns.Select().Title("Select").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center" }).Width(50);
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.Registration).Filterable(false);
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.Contract).Filterable(false);
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.WebStatus).Title("Status").Filterable(false);
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.ArrivedDate).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Filterable(false);
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.Location).Filterable(false);
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.ComponentName).Title("Task").Filterable(false);
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.WorkType).Filterable(false);
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.CreatedDate).Title("Auth Date").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Filterable(false);
                                            columns.Command(commands =>
                                            {
                                                commands.Custom("CompleteLine").Text("Complete").Click("onComplete").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "btn btn-primary" });
                                            })
                                             .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center" }).Width(150).Title("Actions");

                                        })
                                           .Sortable()
                                           .Events(e => e.Change("onChange"))
                                           .Pageable(p => p.Numeric(false).PreviousNext(false))
                                           .Scrollable(sc => sc.Virtual(true).Height(500))
                                           .Render();
                }
```

This is the onChange Event in Javascript. The function remembers the rows after I selecte them, but as soon as I scroll the page so that it loads the 2nd quota of 20 records, it somehow vanishes the selection on the selected rows from the UI, but still remembers them in the background.

```
function onChange(e) {
    // Get the selected rows from the grid.
    $("#Processes tr.k-alt").removeClass("k-alt");
    var rows = e.sender.select();
    selectedRows.length = 0;

    rows.each(function (e) {
        var grid = $("#Processes").data("kendoGrid");
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
        selectedRows.push(dataItem);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [`.PersistSelection(true)`](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/api/kendo.mvc.ui.fluent/gridbuilder#persistselectionsystemboolean) configuration to the Grid definition, so the selected checkboxes remain checked when you scroll back up.
You will need to set the [`DataSource.Model.Id`](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/api/kendo.mvc.ui.fluent/datasourcemodeldescriptorfactory#idsystemlinqexpressionsexpression) as well.